# Unable to display page numbers in DT::renderdatatable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables-1.10

I am trying to render a data table in Shiny but the output doesn'r display the page numbers.

I have tried changing the Paging, DOM options to various parameters but couldn't make it work

```
DT::renderDataTable(expr = { 
    sales_data_filtered() %>%
        group_by(class) %>%
        summarise(sales = sum(sales))%>%
    mutate(sales = scales::dollar(sales)) 

}, options = list(scrollY = "250px",dom = 't',
    pageLength = 5) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite that a little bit.

1. Store the result in a seperate reactive expression:

```
result <- sales_data_filtered() %>%
            group_by(class) %>%
            summarise(sales = sum(sales))%>%
            mutate(sales = scales::dollar(sales))
```

Why exactly do you use the `dom = 't'` option? It means, only the table will get rendered. If not needed, get rid of it.

```
DT::renderDataTable(result(),
              options = list(
                  scrollY = "250px",
                  pageLength = 5,
                  lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20)
              ))
```